# scala regex get all string matching input

Tags: regex, scala

I've below scala function.

```
def getMatchesFor(input: String, matchId: String): List[String] = {
  val regex = s"""${matchId}_\w*""".r
  (regex findAllIn input).toList
}
```

What is the expectation of the function is

```
  val input = "abc_1_1_1_0abc_1_0_1"
  val result = getMatchesFor(input, "abc")
```

`result` should be `List("abc_1_1_1_0", "abc_1_0_1")`

I've tried so far `val r =  s"${matchId}_\\w*".r` but it is not working as expected.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What would the expected result be for `abc_1_xyz`?

Comment: @LeviRamsey the result should be `abc_1_xyz`. Please let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex that matches your needs:

```scala
val regex = s"${matchId}_\\w*?((?=${matchId})|\\W|$$)".r
```

`\w*` must be none greedy, otherwise it would just match everything. It should only match until followed by:

- the next `matchId` using a lookahead `(?=${matchId})`
- a non word character `\W`
- or the line end `$`

An alternative approach might be to simply split the string using `matchId` and extract the remaining match `_\w*` from the parts (ignoring the first split).

Answer (score 1):

Another option using split and a positive lookahead.

See [the positions](https://regex101.com/r/C1GqJb/1) for the split.

```
def getMatchesFor(input: String, matchId: String): List[String] = {
    val regex = s"""(?=${matchId}_)""".r
    regex.split(input).toList
}
```

Output

```
List(abc_1_1_1_0, abc_1_0_1)
```

Comment: simple answer. I've already accepted the other one.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan That is perfectly ok.